# Shutdown, reboot not working

Tags: raspbian, ssh, terminal, failure, reset

I often SSH into my Raspberry Pi, which is connected to my network via a wired connection. The last time I tried to reboot it, though, it failed:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ shutdown now -bash: /sbin/shutdown: cannot execute binary file
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo shutdown now /sbin/shutdown: 1: /sbin shutdown: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I am currently running Raspbian.

Could the files be corrupted? How can I now safely restart it? Will I just have to power cycle it? Last time I did so, I had to reinstall the OS to get it to start up.

Comment: bad things happen. you might need to reimage your SD card.

Comment: did you try this command `sudo shutdown -h now` to shutdown and `sudo shutdown -r 0` to reboot?

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax to power off are:

```
sudo shutdown -h now

sudo halt
```

And for reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r now

sudo reboot
```

Be sure you use either sudo or logged as root himself.

Answer (score 3):

I think the files are corrupted. Just reinstall Raspbian. (You can backup your files before doing that, if you rpi is still running)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the:

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo poweroff
```

Commands

Comment: They don't work either