# Shutdown command is now missing after installing MATE on Raspbian Lite?

Tags: shutdown, raspbian-lite

I recently installed Raspbian Lite (stretch) on my Raspberry Pi 3b+, and followed [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691) to get MATE installed, which worked fine (with the exception of having to use `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` on pretty much all the `apt-get` commands, and a couple that I had to `-f`. (I don't remember which, sorry!)

Before/during installing MATE, I had `shutdown`.

But now when I try to run `shutdown`, I get:

```
bash: shutdown: command not found
```

I found [this answer about Debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/641165/suddenly-shutdown-command-cant-be-found-anymore), but my `systemd-sysv` is installed and up to date:

```
fractangle@pi3bp:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade systemd-sysv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
systemd-sysv is already the newest version (232-25+deb9u2).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also looked at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/22467/84842), but all the answers there seem to be predicated on the presence of `shutdown` (or `halt`, or `reboot`, or `poweroff`) and I have none of those.

I know there's always `systemctl poweroff`, but I miss `shutdown`. *sniff*

Comment: Side notes: 1) You can verify the availability of `shutdown` (and other commands) by `$ whereis shutdown` (for details please read `man whereis`). 2) "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" responds by default to `$ shutdown` with "Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, proceeding with immediate shutdown: Interactive authentication required."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non root user is not allowed to shutdown.

Be sure you really use sudo to execute the command.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Note that the shutdown command is in [`/sbin/shutdown`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=shutdown&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any), which is only in the root user's PATH, which is why the command appears not to exist for regular users.